# Git is showing submodule changes in the upstream repository

Tags: git, git-submodules

*Note: This question references administration topics, but I figured stack overflow was more suited to a `git` question*

I'm using git to manage a rather large stack of configuration files. Each relevant batch of files is  separated off into a submodule, developed on a test server, and then pulled into the "master" branch which is used in the production server.

From my production server, I see:

```
 $ git status

  # On branch master
  # Changes not staged for commit:
  #   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  #   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  #
  # modified:   common/manifests/file.pp
  # modified:   updates (new commits)
```

Here's the thing: `common` is a submodule just like `updates`. I'd expect to see the "new commits" wording here asking me to commit the submodule changes to the "main" repo.

If I drop down into the `common` directory, I see other changes, but most significantly, **NOT** the one that the upstream repository mentions.

```
$ cd common
$ git status

# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   manifests/log.pp
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

It seems like git is aware that the `common` folder is a separate repository only when I'm actually sitting in its working directory, but not when I'm in the upstream directory.

`git --version` comes back with `1.7.11.3`

What's going on here, and how do I get git to start tracking the downstream directory as a submodule again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, the `common` submodule configuration was inadvertently modified, and all references to this repo being a submodule were purged from `.git/modules`, `.gitmodules`, and `.git/config`.

I did a `git rm -r common/` followed by a `git submodule add`, and all is now well.

Moral of the story: Messing around in the `.git` folder has the potential to cause *weird* things to happen.